# Swift How to get amount of values for key in dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

In objective-C it was possible to do it like that:

```
NSString *sectionTitle = [animalSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *sectionAnimals = [animals objectForKey:sectionTitle];
return [sectionAnimals count];
```

Where animals is a [String: String] dictionary
But in Swift 3 there is no method `objectForKey(String: )` for dictionaries or any similar or I can't find it

Comment: use `animals[sectionTitle]`

Comment: Have you tried `animals[sectionTitle]`?

Comment: Please read : [Swift Language Guide: A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1). Even in Objective-C you can (and should) use key and index subscription.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In swift you can do this

```
   let sectionAnimals:Array =  animals[sectionTitle]
```

For example

```
  let animals:[String:String] = ["key" : "value"]
  let sectionTitle = animalSectionTitles[0]
  let sectionAnimals = animals["key"]
```

For more help you can follow this tutorial [Tutorial Link](https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/24/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-swift-3-0/)